How to configure CSP to allow windcave endpoints in my application
In my C# application i am using an external service (Windcave); The payment page gets loaded successfully; and once the required credit card details are provided after processing of the transaction; redirection to my local url (for ex complete page)is not happening. And i get an error

Refused to send form data to 'https://uat.windcave.com/pxmi3/F000073ECDA56FC0370B308090DC2142ADD1B7B679E14563ADE27207D4F3D9691B011EBEE5B20AD2E337555053554A0FAF638FBB257039A943448754C71CB27FB2660FC5C6FD49B29EB58' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' https://uat.paymentexpress.com https://uat.windcave.com http://localhost".

Content security in my web.config is :
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css; img-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' http://localhost:4200; font-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self' http://localhost:4200; navigate-to 'self' http://localhost:4200" />

how to configure CSP to allow their endpoints?
